# What happens, if amino acids are exposed to extreme heat?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, physical-chemistry, molecules, biology

What will happen to amino acids if they are exposed to extremely high temperature such as the temperature of the Sun? Do the amino acids become more simple structures?

Comment: What do you think happens to anything exposed to the temperature of the sun? Amino acids are just mostly just carbon and hydrogen atoms.

Comment: @DKNguyen: … and oxygen and nitrogen (not that this changes much).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, like any molecules the amino acids at high temperature decompose into constituents (atoms), then the letter become ionized (separate into nuclei and electrons), and et even higher temperatures some nuclear transitions can be observed (depending where in the Sun they would find themselves).

For example, [see this article](https://bmcbiophys.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s13628-018-0042-4):

> One concludes that amino acids do not exist in liquid or gaseous form. They decompose endothermally, with heats of decomposition between −72 and −151 kJ/mol, at well defined temperatures between 185 °C and 280 °C.